# openssl error 0200274C with host other than localhost

Tags: openssl, stunnel

**Problem description**:

I've installed and configured stunnel on my machine, and I can send a test message by:

```
echo "hi" | openssl s_client -connect localhost:5143
```

But, when I replace localhost with let's say the IP address of this machine, it fails with:

```
8828:error:0200274C:system library:connect:reason(1868):../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:

8828:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:

connect:errno=0
```

I've limited understanding of SSL, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**: added stunnel config

```
cert = stunnel.pem
sslVersion = all
client = no
[syslog]
accept = 1543
connect = 1514
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How did you setup stunnel?  Is it listening to only localhost?

Comment: Hi @ewokx I should've shared stunnel configuration file in my original post, added now